# Moving elements from bucket to LinkedList but one element gets removed entirely

Tags: java, sorting, nodes, bucket, radix

I am working on a radix sort for my computer science lab in Java, I am encountering a problem however.

After putting all elements into buckets based on the value of the digits, I have a method that moves all elements from the bucket into another linked list.

The problem that occurs is that the movement from the bucket to the linked list results in one missing element. 
The bucket is an array of LinkedLists, pass is a linked list. 
Also, the `removeFirst` method with a string parameter is just removes the first element and returns that node. This is however an overloaded method so the only purpose of `String s` is to point to which method to use. It serves no other purpose.

```
String s = null;
for(int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i ++){
    for (int k = 0; k< bucket[i].numOfNodes();k++){
        Node temp = (bucket[i].removeFirst(s));
        pass.addToEnd(temp);

        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because your tmp is always the same, move this variable up, behind the loop

Comment: How is temp always the same? It changes value